# Facebook API - search place within a distance, between selected ids (or names)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a place search, in a radius, among selected ids (or names).
For example if I've 3 places, with 3 differents ids, (1,2 and 3), I want to search, among these, only the ones that are in the searched range. If place 1 and 2 are in this range, and place 3 is not, i want in the response, only the first 2.

There is some field that permits to add ids, among which search, in the search query?

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?q=*&type=place&center=x,x&distance=500&fields=name,location&limit=100
--> &ids=1,2,3

or is it possible to add center and distance filters in a multiple query?

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?ids=1,2,3&fields=location{longitude,latitude,city}
--> &center=x,x&distance=500

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't support that type of operation, the supported operators on a [place search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search) are `q` for the name, `center` for the centerpoint and `distance` for the distance from that center point

Your second example also isn't a search, it's the code to fetch three individual IDs, but the place object doesn't support searching for other nearby places in that way

if you want a search like you've described you'd need to account for that in your own code by using the location of the 'known' places and determining the point which is in the 'middle' of those places and the 'distance' from that center you'd need to find places within your required area